# Linksys RVL200 VPN Connection w/ Windows 8 w/o 3rd Party Software

Tags: windows-8, router, vpn

I own a Linksys RVL200 VPN router at my office. I used to be able to tunnel in using Cisco's software but I recently switched to Windows 8.

As of right now, the same Cisco software apparently does not work with Windows 8.

I wanted to know if there were some way of configuring a VPN tunnel with the tools already available in Windows 8.

Comment: Maybe, but you'll need to know the settings the router-side of the VPN use.  Do you know those?  If so, please edit them into the question.  Which Cisco client are you using?  Have you checked www.cisco.com for an updated version?  What have you tried already?  What were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows already have ability to set up VPN. Whether it is compatible with Cisco ones or not, that is debatable, and for you test.

Steps to set up VPN:

- Right click on your network connection (bottom right corner) - choose Open Network and Sharing Center.
- Click on "Set up New Connection or Network"
- "Connect to a workplace"
- Use my Internet Connection (VPN)
- And from there, just enter the details of your VPN server (the remote server address) and you also need to know the security of the VPN server.